# How do I determine whether a randomly generated number is a multiple of 150?

Tags: c#, if-statement, multiplication

I'm creating a basic mystery box program using randomly generated numbers to determine what rarity item they get. However, if the number they get is a multiple of 150, I want them to get a particular item. I'm not sure how to determine whether the random number is a multiple of 150 though.

```
else if (num is in 150 times tables)
{
    code...
}
```

Comment: As a kid, I always had trouble to learn the table of 150

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Modulo Operator '%'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator) and check the remainder.

```
if (num % 150 == 0)
{
    // It is divisable, do something
}
else
{
    // Not divisable, do something else
}
```

The modulo operator basically says "How many times can I divide the first number by the second, and what do I have left over?". In this example if `num` divided by `150` has `0` left over then it fits perfectly and you know it's a multiple.

Comment: So the `%` is used to figure out the remainder of a division calculation?
e.g `151 % 150` would return `1`?

Comment: @someguy76 Yes. That's what it does.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does. [Here is an example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4fHFIP).

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated, and great explanation(:

Comment: No problem. Just as an FYI since you seem new if an answer has answered your question fully it's normally polite to click the green check mark and 'accept' the answer.